# How to migrate to git from two SVN repositories?

Tags: svn, git

We use SVN as our VCS, but wish to migrate to git. All is good, but a few months ago our SVN server had a serious RAID problems (so much that it became unusable) plus at the same day no IT person was available to restore the repository from the backups. So, we have setup a temporary SVN server on a certain workstation from the most recent version that we had. The net result is:

1. We have a few months of work on the temporary SVN server (the revisions there start from 1, of course)
2. There is a new VCS server machine with the pre-crash SVN repository restored there, but no one uses it yet, because someone has to merge the temporary repository there somehow and no one has the time.
3. In addition, we want to migrate to git, because SVN is just too much pain to work with - merges are killing us.

Can anyone advice on the best process to end up with a git repository, which would contain the old SVN repository merged with the temporary one?

BTW, the new VCS server is a linux machine.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: #2 I assume by merge you mean keep all the history so in that case see if http://svn2svn.codeplex.com/ . I haven't used it but maybe it can help.

Comment: Yes indeed. I want to keep all the history.

Answer (score 1):

"merges are killing us." - merges are what git is good at :-)

Rather than merge the two svn repositories try using git-svn to pull in the original and then the temporary.

There's no actual need to touch the new server until you have a git repository you are happy with, on a linux workstation for example. Play with it until you're happy then pull it onto the server.

Comment: OK, I will try this approach. Unfortunately, I do not have a linux machine to play around. The workstations are running Windows...

Comment: Nothing wrong with doing it on the server. Just seems a shame to risk messing it up while trying things out.  git-svn is availably for windows via cygwin.